# PHP and Mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

I use os X yosemite on my mac. I have been facing issues with PHP and Mysql connection lately. I could not connect PHP to mysql using this statement

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$passwd);
        if($link)
        {
            echo "Connection successful";
        }
        else 
        {
            $msg=mysql_error();
            echo $msg;
        }
```

I have seen some recommendation over the internet to link some sock files (I am mad at myswl for not understanding and recording what I did). After those sock changes, it worked fine. Now I restarted the machine, and a couple of days later, I am not able to connect to mysql both directly as well as through PHP. I get the following error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I tried the suggestions of modifying the php.ini, but it didn't help.

Thanks for your help.

This is how the PHP.ini looks like:

```
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket= tmp/mysql.sock as well as /var/mysql/mysql.soc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

More information
-----------------
mymac:mysql abc$ cd /var/mysql
mymac:mysql abc$ ls -ltr

/*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  15 Feb  6  2014 mysql.soc -> /tmp/mysql.sock

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  15 Nov 30 10:07 mysql.sock -> /tmp/mysql.sock */
-----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you connect to `localhost` the socket connector is used, but when you connect to `127.0.0.1` the TCP/IP connector is used. You could try using `127.0.0.1` if the socket connector is not enabled/working.

**OR**
Configure your my.cnf (usually in the /etc/mysql/ folder) file with

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

check if you are running `MySQL` or not.

also try changing your permission to mysql folder, you can try:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

that solved it for me

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Sadly, it doesn't work either. It gives me the following message.Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root

Comment: The surprising part is, when I made the change (Which I don't remember), the connection worked fine, I was able to connect to mysql from PHP. Now inspite of changing all the combination of the mysql.sock it doesn't work...

Comment: I am going through the comments on the thread that addresses the above mentioned issue. First few are not helping either :(